# AVAssetWriter startWriting fails when running in background

Tags: ios, avassetwriter

I am trying to save images into a video file, while the app is in the background

I try to create the AVAssetWriter and start writing but this operation fails (returns NO).
Here are some checks I performed:

- The file does not exist
- I invoke `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithName: expirationHandler:]`  prior to running my
  code
- The status of the assetWriter prior to calling startWriting is `AVAssetWriterStatusUnknown`

The Error I receive (in the code below `videoWriter.error`) is :
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo=0x17e1e710 {NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x17ec85d0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -16980.)", NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-16980)}

And to be specific on the underlying error:
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16980 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -16980.)

I couldn't find any explanation to this behaviour or error code

Please advise!

```
- (BOOL)_createAssetWriterWithFrameSize:(CGSize)frameSize filePath:(NSString *)filePath{
       NSURL *filePathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

        NSError *error = nil;

        AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:filePathURL
                                                               fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                                                  error:&error];
        if(error!=nil){
            LogDebug(@"Error creating %@", error);
        }

        if (videoWriter) {

            NSDictionary *videoSettings = @{AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264,
                                            AVVideoWidthKey: @(frameSize.width),
                                            AVVideoHeightKey: @(frameSize.height),//};

                                            };

            AVAssetWriterInput *writerInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                                 outputSettings:videoSettings];

            NSDictionary *attributes = @{(NSString *)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: @(kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB),
                                         (NSString *)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey: @(frameSize.width),
                                         (NSString *)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey: @(frameSize.height)};


            AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = nil;
            if(attributes!=nil){
                adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput
                                                                                                                    sourcePixelBufferAttributes:attributes];
            }
            if ([videoWriter canAddInput:writerInput]) {
                [videoWriter addInput:writerInput];

                writerInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;


                BOOL start = [videoWriter startWriting];

                if (start) {
                    [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

                }
                else{

                    LogInfo(@"Could not start writing to video file due to %@. file is %@", videoWriter.error, filePath);
                    id o = [videoWriter.error.userInfo objectForKey:NSUnderlyingErrorKey];
                    if(o!=nil){
                        LogDebug(@"Failed writing, underlying error is %@", o);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: how did u fixed that plz?

Comment: unfortunately I had to workaround this.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?